# Error: Cannot call database.adapter.underlying Adapter while the database is being reset watermelondb

Tags: android, react-native, watermelondb

> Exception com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: Error: Cannot call database.adapter.underlyingAdapter while the database is being reset

I can see multiple crashes in the play store with the above stack trace, I am using watermelon DB in react native.

what might causing this issue?

Answer (score 1):

For this to occur two things need to happen:

- You've initiated the reset of the watermelondb `await database.unsafeResetDatabase()`
- A component which is connected to
  watermelondb e.g. via the `withObservables` HOC gets mounted and makes a database request.

So you have to check which component gets mounted during the reset process.